# strip tags from post content pulled as excerpt wp 3.6

Tags: wordpress

I'm using the following code to pull 3 posts onto a static wp page. It pulls the posts but it includes tags, so I need to strip them out. I assume its with strip_tags but I cant find an example, and I have no idea where to add it.

```
<?php
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '3');
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ) {

    echo "
    <div><article><header class='entry-header'><h1 class='entry-title'><a href='".get_permalink($recent['ID'])."'>".$recent[post_title]."</a></h1></header>
    <div class='entry-summary'><p>".substr($recent["post_content"], 0 , 150)."</p>
    <a href='".get_permalink($recent['ID'])."'>".get_the_post_thumbnail($recent['ID']). "</a></div>

    </article></div>"

    ;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the excerpt of the post content use [wp_trim_excerpt](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_excerpt).

The excerpt word amount will be 55 words and if the amount is greater than that, then the string ' [...]' will be appended to the excerpt. If the string is less than 55 words, then the content will be returned as is.

Use it like

```
$excerpt = wp_trim_excerpt( $recent['post_content'] );

<div class='entry-summary'><p>". $excerpt. "</p>
<a href='".get_permalink($recent['ID'])."'>".get_the_post_thumbnail($recent['ID']). "</a></div>
```

To increase the amount of trim words use the hook [excerpt_length](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/excerpt_length)